# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I'm breaking my head in here, I'm getting this error and I really don't know how to fix it.
When I try to run this query I'm getting an error message:

```
SELECT A.INTERACTION_ID,
       A.SERVICE_AUDIT_ID,
       A.INTERACTION_STATUS_INFO,
       A.INTERACTION_MESSAGE_TEXT,
       A.INTERACTION_START,
       B.SERVICE_RESPONSE_CODE,
       B.SERVICE_RESPONSE_INFO,
       C.DELIVERY_RECEIPT_STATUS_INFO
  FROM CONSENT_SERVICE_INTERACTION A
       INNER JOIN CONSENT_SERVICE_TRANSACTION B
         ON A.SERVICE_AUDIT_ID = B.SERVICE_AUDIT_ID
       INNER JOIN CONSENT_SMS_INTERACTION C
         ON A.CLIENT_TRACKING_ID = C.CLIENT_TRACKING_ID
 WHERE     A.INTERACTION_MESSAGE_TEXT = 'OK'
       AND B.SERVICE_RESPONSE_INFO = 'OK'

 ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
 Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

the weird thing is if I add an extra condition it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle "SQL Error: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752719/oracle-sql-error-missing-in-or-out-parameter-at-index-1)

Comment: How are you running this query? Through Java? Directly in SQL*Plus/Toad/SQL Developer etc? Something else?

Comment: syntactically I can't find any error ;(

Comment: have you tried putting a semi colon at the end of your statement?

Comment: There must be a colon (:) somewhere in your SQL text. Not in your query - but if you e.g. run it from SQL Developer it is easy to have some extra mess in the statement. Also consider adding the ending ;

Comment: Thanks to all! I ran it in TOAD and worked! I guess there is a bug in SQL developer