# oracle query giving Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1 error

Tags: java, hibernate

This oracle query giving *"missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1"* error

```sql
select
   count(this_.CHECKIN_DATE) as y0_,
   u1_.EMPLOYEE_ID as y1_,
   u1_.FIRST_NAME as y2_,
   u1_.LAST_NAME as y3_,
   u1_.STATUS as y4_,
   l3_.LOCATION as y5_,
   this_.SOURCE as y6_,
   vt2_.VISIT_REASON as y7_ 
from
   VFIT_CHECKIN this_ 
   left outer join
      VFIT_LOCATIONS l3_ 
      on this_.LOCATION_ID = l3_.LOCATION_ID 
   left outer join
      VFIT_USER u1_ 
      on this_.MEMBER_NO = u1_.MEMBER_NO 
   left outer join
      VFIT_VISIT vt2_ 
      on this_.VISIT_ID = vt2_.VISIT_ID 
where
   (
      lower(u1_.STATUS) like ? 
   )
   and ? <= 
   (
      select
         count(*) as y0_ 
      from
         VFIT_CHECKIN child_ 
      where
         child_.MEMBER_NO = this_.MEMBER_NO
   )
   and ? >= 
   (
      select
         count(*) as y0_ 
      from
         VFIT_CHECKIN child_ 
      where
         child_.MEMBER_NO = this_.MEMBER_NO
   )
group by
   u1_.EMPLOYEE_ID,
   u1_.FIRST_NAME,
   u1_.LAST_NAME,
   u1_.STATUS,
   l3_.LOCATION,
   this_.SOURCE,
   vt2_.VISIT_REASON 
order by
   u1_.FIRST_NAME asc,
   u1_.LAST_NAME asc;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle "SQL Error: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752719/oracle-sql-error-missing-in-or-out-parameter-at-index-1)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, describe more the problem and make sure to [formata your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)